# Assume that the probability for an angle $\phi$ is $P(\phi) = \lambda\phi^2$. The game pays $\$1000$ times the angle. What is $\lambda$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

Wheel of fortune: Assume that the probability for an angle $\phi$ is $P(\phi) = \lambda\phi^2$. The game pays $\$1000$ times the angle.

a) What is $\lambda$?

b) Find the expectation and the variance of the game.

Comments: I've been thinking of this question for days. Other than an idea that there being $360$ degrees may be part of the solution, I don't know where to start.

I interpreted $\lambda$ as follows:

$P(φ) = \lambda\phi^2 = 1 \Rightarrow \lambda =\frac{1}{\phi^2} $

At this point answers are nice, however explanations will be crucial. I really want to know how a and b work, and if my ideas were in the right direction.

Comment: Hint:  The probability of landing *anywhere* on the wheel is : $\mathsf P(2\pi)=1$ is it not?

Comment: Also, how are you defining $\varphi$? $\in (-\pi,\pi)$? $(0,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There must be
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\lambda\varphi^2\,d\varphi=\lambda\frac13(2\pi)^3=1,
$$
hence $\lambda=\frac{3}{8\pi^3}$. If we have density, the rest are calculations.

Comment: You must mean lambda=3/(8pi^3)

Comment: @AspiringMathematician Thank you! Corrected. There was `{}` instead of `()` in the value of the integral, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got (1) down.  What you want is to use $\mathsf P(2\pi)=1$ to determine the parameter, $\lambda$. (Note: this is assuming $\mathsf P$ is the cumulative probability function.)

For (2) you'll want to use

$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(1000\varphi) &= \int_0^{2\pi} 1000\phi\mathsf P(\operatorname d \phi)
& \text{where }\mathsf P(\operatorname d \phi)=\frac{\operatorname d \mathsf P(\phi)}{\operatorname d \phi}\operatorname d \phi
\\ & = 1000\int_0^{2\pi} \phi \times(2\lambda\phi)\operatorname d \phi
\\[2ex]
\mathsf {Var}(1000\varphi) & = \left(\int_0^{2\pi} 10^6\phi^2\mathsf P(\operatorname d\phi)  \right)-\mathsf E(1000\varphi)^2
\\ & =2\times10^6\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \lambda \phi^3\operatorname d \phi\right)-\mathsf E(1000\varphi)^2
\end{align}$